# Play 2 reverse routing, get route from controller method

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using the Play 2.2.3 framework, given I have a route like this one in my routes file :

```
GET         /event                                 controllers.Event.events
```

How can I programatically get the "/event" knowing the method I am trying to reach, in this case 'controllers.Authentication.authenticate' ?

I need it for test purpose, because I would like to have better test waiting not for the route itself but for the controllers method really called. So maybe there is another solution than getting the route and test it this way like I do for now :

```
//Login with good password and login
    val Some(loginResult) = route(FakeRequest(POST, "/login").withFormUrlEncodedBody(
      ("email", email)
      , ("password", password)))
    status(loginResult)(10.seconds)     mustBe 303
    redirectLocation(loginResult).get mustBe "/event"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You construct the reverse route in this way:

```
[full package name].routes.[controller].[method]
```

In your example:

```
 controllers.routes.Authentication.authenticate
 controllers.routes.Events.events
```

But say you broke your packages out like `controllers.auth` and `controllers.content`, then they would be:

```
 controllers.auth.routes.Authentication.authenticate
 controllers.content.routes.Events.events
```

The reverse routes return a `Call`, which contains an HTTP method and URI. In your tests you can construct a `FakeRequest` with a `Call`:

```
 FakeRequest(controllers.routes.Authentication.authenticate)
```

And you can also use it to test the redirect URI:

```
 val call: Call = controllers.routes.Events.events 
 redirectLocation(loginResult) must beSome(call.url)
```

Comment: How does it work if I am using a `SIRD` router? In my case, the `routes.conf` has `->      /ws/users                      WSRouters.UserRouter`. `UserRouter` gets `UserController` passed as argument and I am calling `UserController'` `verifyUser` method. How do I reverse route this/